# Laravel: How to get products from Multi Level Category

Tags: laravel, tree, categories

I was looking in my code and I realised that I work with arrays.

This is how I get the products from a Multi Level Category:

```php
    public function childs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id')->whereColumn('id', '!=', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function descendants()
    {
        $descendants = [];

        foreach ($this->childs as $category) 
        {
            array_push($descendants, $category);
            $descendants = array_merge($descendants, $category->descendants());
        }

        return $descendants;
    }

    public function treeProducts()
    {
        $categories = [$this];
        $categories = array_merge($categories, $this->descendants());

        $ids = [];

        forEach($categories as $category)
        {
            array_push($ids, $category->id);
        }

        return Product::whereIn('category_id', $ids);
    }
```

Calling treeProducts will get the products from every subtree. But the problem is that I store the categories and products in arrays, working with 500+ products I think will flood the RAM.

I can't do this process with Query Builder, without using arrays?

Comment: You should look into using `left` and `right` columns to allow you to query descendants without a recursive `foreach` loop. This package has some useful features for dealing with tree structures in Laravel: https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset

Comment: I don't want a balanced tree..

Comment: I wasn't talking about *balanced* trees, but you do have a tree structure. I was just saying there are more effective ways to get descendants. Your question also asked about doing things with a query builder instead of arrays, and the package would let you do things like `with('descendants.products')`.